# Delete entire column which dont contain value from an array

Tags: excel, vba

I need to delete entire columns in a worksheet based on if a cell in that column contains a value from a cell or not. I found this piece of code on an another site, which I can't link to for some reason. This code works flawlessly for me, except it deletes all columns if a cell contains a value from an array. i want it to do the opposite: Delete a column if it DOESN'T contain a value from an array. Basically reverse on what it does.

Here is the code:

```
Sub ModifyTICBData()

Dim varList As Variant
    Dim lngarrCounter As Long
    Dim rngFound As Range, rngToDelete As Range
    Dim strFirstAddress As String

    'Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    varList = VBA.Array("Departure Time", "Trailer Type", "From Depot / Store Name ", "Trip Position", "To Store Number", "To Store / Depot Name", "Product Code", "Pallets") 'I want to keep columns with these values, NOT DELETE THEM

    For lngarrCounter = LBound(varList) To UBound(varList)

        With Sheets("Nastavit D").UsedRange
            Set rngFound = .Find( _
                                What:=varList(lngarrCounter), _
                                Lookat:=xlWhole, _
                                SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                                SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                MatchCase:=True)

            If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then
                strFirstAddress = rngFound.Address

                If rngToDelete Is Nothing Then
                    Set rngToDelete = rngFound
                Else
                    If Application.Intersect(rngToDelete, rngFound.EntireColumn) Is Nothing Then
                        Set rngToDelete = Application.Union(rngToDelete, rngFound)
                    End If
                End If

                Set rngFound = .FindNext(After:=rngFound)

                Do Until rngFound.Address = strFirstAddress
                    If Application.Intersect(rngToDelete, rngFound.EntireColumn) Is Nothing Then
                        Set rngToDelete = Application.Union(rngToDelete, rngFound)
                    End If
                    Set rngFound = .FindNext(After:=rngFound)
                Loop
            End If
        End With
    Next lngarrCounter

    If Not rngToDelete Is Nothing Then rngToDelete.EntireColumn.Delete

    'Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

Comment: The `If Not rngFound Is Nothing then` means that the following code will be executed if it found the item. To do the opposite, remove the `Not`

Comment: @romulax14 I've tried that but the code then does nothing at all.

Comment: I'll write an answer with explanations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, use your code as it is, but replace:

```
If Not rngToDelete Is Nothing Then rngToDelete.EntireColumn.Delete
```

with:

```
Dim rngDel As Range
Set rngDel = NotIntersectRng(Sheets("Nastavit D").UsedRange, rngToDelete)
If Not rngDel Is Nothing Then rngDel.EntireColumn.Delete
```

And copy the next function in the same module:

```
Private Function NotIntersectRng(rng As Range, rngF As Range) As Range
  Dim rngNI As Range, i As Long, j As Long
  For i = 1 To rng.Columns.count
    If Intersect(rng.cells(1, i).EntireColumn, rngF) Is Nothing Then    
        If rngNI Is Nothing Then
            Set rngNI = rng.cells(1, i)
        Else
            Set rngNI = Union(rngNI, rng.cells(1, i))
        End If
    End If
  Next i
  If Not rngNI Is Nothing Then Set NotIntersectRng = rngNI
End Function
```

The function checks the columns not intersecting with the ones containing the array strings and creates a range. This one will be used to delete entire column...

Comment: It works!!! Ive modified the 'If Not rngDel Is Nothing Then rngDel.EntireColumn.Delete' part to 'If Not rngDel Is Nothing Then rngDel.EntireColumn.ClearContents' to just delete the values instead.

Comment: @Tomas Perlecky: Glad I could help! I tried answering the question as it was, but of course, you can use the built range in the way you need.